# Migrating Azure Table Storage to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

Are there any tools available to migrate Azure Table storage to Cosmos DB to access using Table APIs?  I found [Data Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data) but it only supports table storage access through Document API.

**UPDATE :** I tried Data Factory copy data feature to copy from Table Storage to Document DB ( i guess it is cosomosDb now). But it didn't copy any data to Cosmos DB though Data Factory pipeline says it copied so and so amount of data but i don't see any entities in the Target Cosmos Db Table.

What is the best way to migrate to Cosmos DB and use Table APIs ?

Comment: Had this problem too. I used a little bit of code. I published my [code  here](https://github.com/m-rom/azure-migrate). Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to migrate to Cosmos DB and use Table APIs ?

If I understand correctly you want to migrate Azure Table Storage to Cosmos table API DB. If it is that case and  program is possible, we could do that with Azure supplied [Windows Azure Storage Premium Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage-PremiumTable/0.1.0-preview) SDK. It is a preview version. The following is my demo code, it works correctly on side.

1.We need to implement **TableEntity** and add our customize properties. property is `case sensitive`

```
    public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
    {

        public CustomerEntity() { }
        public Type tableEntityProperty { get; set; } 
        ...
    }
```

2.Add **Get could table** function

```
public static CloudTable GetTable(string connectionstring,string tableName)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount destStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionstring);
            CloudTableClient destTableClient = destStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable destTable = destTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
            destTable.CreateIfNotExists();
            return destTable;
        }
```

3.Try to query the table entities from the Azure storage table and add it to Azure cosmos table.

```
  var sourceConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageName;AccountKey=yourkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
  var destConnectionstring = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=cosmostableAPIAccount;AccountKey=yourkey;TableEndpoint=https://tomtableapi.documents.azure.com";

  CloudTable sourceTable = GetTable(sourceConnectionString, "source table");
  CloudTable destTable = GetTable(destConnectionstring, "dest table");
  TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();

     foreach (CustomerEntity entity in sourceTable.ExecuteQuery(query))
     {
          TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
          // Execute the insert operation.
          destTable.Execute(insertOperation);
     }
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.14.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="7.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="7.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage-PremiumTable" version="0.1.0-preview" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks. But i have 100 tables at least with millions of entities in each table. So i don't think this solution is robust in case of any unexpected failure and we cannot guarantee the integrity of the data.  I am looking for more robust solution/tool  such as `Data Factory` or `Data Migration tools` to do this job.

Comment: Based on my experience, we could use Data factory to do that. It seems that there is no **Data Migration tools** to do that, if any idea please give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to Azure team.

Comment: in Data Factory what should be the target database. Is it `Document Db` ? If yes, where do we specify the model we want to use to access that database. In this case `Table API`.

Comment: Currently, I also can reproduce this (don't see any entities in the Target Cosmos Db Table). If  Table API is not the only choice, we could use Azure DocumentDb API. We also can conact to askcosmosdb@microsoft.com to get more help. I have sent an email to askcosmosdb@microsoft.com, if any update, I will update it on this.

Comment: Thanks mate.   I have also sent an email to ` askcosmosdb@microsoft.com` and they said they are planning to release a migration tool for Table APIs end of this week or early next week.

Comment: Azure cosmos db team is planning to fix this issue.(don't see any entities in the Target Cosmos Db Table)

Comment: any ETA on this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no ETA from their‘s reply.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT I am curious if this ever improved?